# Resizeable text input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use from bootstrap in my site, i wan't to create something like [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/recreate-github-search-box).

my html code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> 'Find'</button>
</form>
```

How i can resize the input?

Comment: What has one tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  tutorial you specified , css code is there : 
Add this part to your html page : [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/btphE/)

```
<style stype='text/css'>

input[type=text].search_form
{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
width:200px;
min-height: 28px;
padding: 4px 20px 4px 8px;
font-size: 12px;
-moz-transition: all .2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
transition: all .2s linear;
}

input[type=text]:focus.search_form
{
width: 400px;
border-color: #51a7e8;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 5px rgba(81,167,232,0.5);
outline: none;
 }

</style>

<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> 'Find'</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.navbar .search-input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 400px;
    border-color: #51a7e8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 5px rgba(81,167,232,0.5);
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like I did on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkzyB/)

```
.form-control.search-input[type=text]:focus {
width: 400px;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 5px rgba(81,167,232,0.5);
outline: none;
-moz-transition: all .2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you posted has the code you need. You are going to want to target your input and add your transition options:

```
.search-input { 
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Then on focus you set the new width:

```
.search-input:focus { 
    width: 400px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5UZd/